# Setting up a gcloud appspot domain for a flask api- Getting URL not found error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am currently trying to setup a gcloud appspot domain. I am consistently getting this error when I attempt to open up my appspot project on the browser:

***Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.***

Here is my code. How can I fix this?

app.yaml -

```
runtime: python


env: flex


entrypoint: gunicorn -t 120 -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config: 
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1


resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 8
  disk_size_gb: 20
  
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

main.py

```
app=Flask(__name__)
api=Api(app)
.
.
.
api.add_resource(Multi,'/sentiment/<num>')
api.add_resource(Analyze,'/analyze/<query>')
api.add_resource(AddLike,'/addLike/<likedMovie>')
api.add_resource(AddDislike,'/addDislike/<dislikedMovie>')
api.add_resource(GetRecommendation,'/getRecommendation/<userID>')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port=os.getenv('PORT',5000))
    app.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

(In between, it contains the classes and methods to serve the api calls)

and my file structure looks like:(inside root folder)

- app.yaml
- main.py
- (other files)

Comment: Maybe an issue with your code, can you share the code inside `main.py`?

Comment: I edited the code to add the main.py code, kindly have a look

Comment: Did you try the path `/sentiment/123`?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it says {"message": "Internal Server Error"}

Comment: Thus, it works!! And the Dondi answer is the correct one!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to deploy on App Engine is a web app. You cannot deploy Android apps on App Engine. If you look at the picture in the Final System section, the system has two main parts and that is your Android app (client) and a request server. You are deploying the request server in App Engine Flex (which is a managed Compute Engine VM under the hood).

From what I can understand, your request server is designed to handle backend API calls. If you want to display some sort of UI interface when users access `/`, then register the URL to a function that renders your view page.

I suggest that you study how Flask app routing works. You get that error because the URL (`/`) is not associated to any of your functions on your app. You can get started at Flask [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.route). Here's a [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/main.py#L150) from GitHub

Comment: I tried to use the exact address with which the functions are registered. If you would like to know I'm trying to deploy the android app like it's done in this Github project
https://github.com/3ZadeSSG/ContentBased-Movie-Recommendation-using-Sentiment-Analysis

Comment: Hi Sourabh. I updated my answer to further explain. I tested the repo and the functions seems to work as intended except the URL `/sentiment`. I suggest looking into the log section because there are errors in it, and post a new question if you need further help to fix it.